# Location of breakdowns in power transformers

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-engineering

Where exactly are [breakdowns](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Breakdown_voltage#/Electrical_apparatus) occuring in power transformers? Means, between which components exactly?

[image: img]

Comment: [Troubleshooting Transformer In Power Substation And Detailed Failure Investigation](https://electrical-engineering-portal.com/troubleshooting-transformer-failure)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see the specific information there?